# What does "referenced file offline" mean in Photos?

Tags: macos, photos, aperture, photos.app

I have large numbers of files in my Photos from my recently migrated Aperture library that show a crossed out reference icon

[image]

indicating that the "referenced file is offline". If I try to access such files I get a dialog asking me to indicate a *specific* folder to allow Photos access. Sometimes this (tedious) process works, but often it does not, since the specified folder *does not exist*. This happens even though the referenced file was present in Aperture before migration. What's the user model here; where did my photos go?

Comment: If you open aperture, get information on that photo. My guess is that your library has a thumbnail and not the actual master. Once you've gotten a handle on the Aperture library state, you might ditch your Photos library, fix the Aperture by consolidating / relocating the masters and then importing into Photos again.

Comment: @bmike: That sounds right. It seems like Aperture just had a slightly different way of presenting offline photos that made the fact that they were offline less prominent. It's still a pain to have to manually relocate the folders containing the ones that aren't offline.

Comment: Consolidating files inside Aperture can be done in one go.  While this can still take time, you do not need to select each project for it.  Just select "Photos" from the inspector pane and then select all pictures (Cmd+A) and consolidate them.  Alternatively, you can also filter them using the search field on the upper right above the actual photo space and filter for referenced files only.  Just don't forget to clear the filter again afterwards or you may wonder in the future where all your pictures went in this view.

Comment: Useful, except what you mean is "*could have been done* in on go". There was no warning to do this before migration, and there should have been.